# Image with PHP address

Tags: php, html, ios, image

I am building an app which gets content out of HTML pages. I've encounter a problem:

There is an image displayed in a HTML page, but the image URL points to a PHP address. When I copy and open this address in a web browser, the browser fails to realize its an image and displays strings instead.

The page that contains the image:
http://h.acfun.tv/

The image URL:
http://wiki.acfun.tv/keyheaders/cover.php

I am not familiar with server side script, I wonder how they achieved this, and how can I get the correct image URL from this PHP address?

By the way the app that I am making is an iOS app.

Comment: That image is a link which points to a php file so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Refer to [PHP: header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for some various examples, including other headers that you might want to set beyond the `Content-Type`. At the very least, `Content-Length`, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is responding with the actual image, however their Content-Type is incorrect so when you go to the page directly, your browser thinks it's some text. Pointing an img tag at that URL will show the image as expected (which is in JFIF format).

How their achieving it is a simple case of something like the following:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('theImage.jfif');
?>
```

A better method which would remove the Content-Type problem if you are intending on doing this too would be to include the correct Content-Type header:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: image/jfif');
    echo file_get_contents('theImage.jfif');
?>
```

Having said that, **I wouldn't reccommend doing this except for some very particular cases**. It affects how the image is cached by the browser (in their case, it's not cached at all), and invokes PHP where a simple static file request would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The URL points to a JPEG image, but the server responds with a header like it's text/html

```
Content-type: text/html
```

istead of

```
Content-type: image/jpeg
```

I guess the browser, since the url is inside an **img** tag attempts successuflly to determine the image type by inspecting the content of the data returned.

If you type the address directly in the browser it doesn't take care of determining if the content requested is image but obey to the content type of the request "text/html"

---

If you have access to the server code, the PHP script should tell the browser that the content returned is an image. On way to do that is properly setting the header of the response with the **header()** function called before any content is sent out.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

---

If you have to display that content in an iOS application just treat the data received as a JPEG image.

Comment: That isn't his php script.

Answer (score 0):

That link is returning `Content-Type    text/html`, so the data may be an image but the server is telling any client (browser / your app) that the data is HTML. You either need to change the server to tell the truth about the data type or get the raw data from the URL and treat it differently (by trying to load an image from it).

Comment: The first link has the same URL, but its able to display the image properly, why? Its it because they placed the URL inside an <img> tag?

Comment: I guess the `img` tag doesn't care about the returned headers, it just tries to create an image. Not 100% sure, you'd need to check the HTML spec...

Answer (score 0):

It is to do with the `Content-Type` of the request, so that a browser knows what kind of data it needs to display. The server that is serving cover.php, the `MIME` type is set to `text/html` so your app is attempting to display it as text, rather than the correct image format.